# In Dockerfile, do I have to COPY the files from stage "a" to stage "b" if stage "b" is defined as "FROM a AS b"?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use multi stage Dockerfile with stages `build` and `start`, as in:

```
FROM <whatever> as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./a.file ./
COPY ./b.file ./

RUN <build command>

FROM build as start

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/a.file ./
COPY --from=build /app/b.file ./

CMD <start command>
```

I wonder, in `start` stage, do I have to do `COPY --from=build <...files>` again?

In other words, does `start` reuse file system of `build`? If it does, then I don't need to copy the files again (since all files necessary for `start` have already been copied in `build`). Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you have a second stage?

Comment: @BMitch The `build` stage is cached if its inputs haven't changed (I do have some difference in file content between the stages, – i.e., some files are copied in `start` but not in `build`)

Comment: The build cache is per step, not per stage. As Hans answered, the second `FROM` is not needed unless you build the first stage only, or reuse the second stage multiple times elsewhere in your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't. In your Dockerfile, the second `FROM` statement doesn't do anything at all, since the `start` stage continues on from the `build` stage. So you can remove the second `FROM` statement and your final image will be the same as before.

The reason people use multi-stage Dockerfiles is usually to build the app in the first stage with an image that contains a build environment. Then, after the build is done, you start a new run-time image and copy over the built application.

That way your final image doesn't contain the complete build environment and you create a smaller final image.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you describe a Dockerfile in which the start stage does not use build stage, but the "empty" one (e.g., `FROM node AS build`, and then `FROM node AS start`), right?